# Display "Loading" Until Data Is Displayed, Using Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

Im currently trying to learn knockout so please keep all answers in knockout.
I  have a contact list for a company NBI, at the top of the contact list is displayed " NBI Has # Employees". Currently I have a timeout that fills in the initial contacts after 5 seconds. What I would like to have happen is to have " NBI Has # Employees" not display until the 5 seconds is passed and the employees are displayed, id would also like for "Loading " to be displayed in place of the " NBI Has # Employees" until the employees are displayed then have loading replaced with " NBI Has # Employees".

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/grahamwalsh/2cf8nr3t/

here is my code

html

```
<div class='NbiEmployees'> 

<h2>NBI Employees</h2>
<h3>NBI has <span data-bind="text: employees().length"></span> Employees</h3>
<div id='employeesList'>
    <table class='employeesEditor'>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Phone numbers</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: employees">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input data-bind='value: firstName' />
                    <div><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeEmployee'>Delete</a></div>
                </td>
                <td><input data-bind='value: lastName' /></td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: phones">
                            <tr>
                                <td><input data-bind='value: type' /></td>
                                <td><input data-bind='value: number' /></td>
                                <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removePhone'>Delete</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.addPhone'>Add number</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<p>
    <button data-bind='click: addEmployee'>Add an Employee</button>
    <button data-bind='click: save, enable: employees().length > 0'>Save to JSON</button>
</p>

<textarea data-bind='value: lastSavedJson' rows='5' cols='60' disabled='disabled'> </textarea>
```

CSS

```
body { font-family: arial; font-size: 14px; }

.NbiEmployees { padding: 1em; background-color: #EEEEDD; border: 1px solid #CCC; max-width: 655px; }
.NbiEmployees input { font-family: Arial; }
.NbiEmployees b { font-weight: bold; }
.NbiEmployees p { margin-top: 0.9em; margin-bottom: 0.9em; }
.NbiEmployees select[multiple] { width: 100%; height: 8em; }
.NbiEmployees h2 { margin-top: 0.4em; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em; }

 .NbiEmployees TR { vertical-align: top; }
 .NbiEmployees TABLE, .NbiEmployees TD, .NbiEmployees TH { padding: 0.2em; border-width: 0; margin: 0; }
 .NbiEmployees TD A { font-size: 0.8em; text-decoration: none; }
 .NbiEmployees table.contactsEditor > tbody > TR { border-bottom: 1px solid silver; }
 .NbiEmployees td input { width: 8em; }

  li { list-style-type: disc; margin-left: 20px; }
```

knockout

```
var EmployeesModel = function () {
var self = this;
//self.employees = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(employees, function (employee) {
    //return { firstName: employee.firstName, lastName:    employee.lastName, phones: ko.observableArray(employee.phones) };
//}));

self.employees = ko.observableArray(
    );


setTimeout(function () {
    var data = [
        {
            firstName: "Graham", lastName: "Walsh", phones: [
              { type: "Office", number: "(555) 121-2121" },
              { type: "Mobile", number: "(555) 123-4567" }]
        },
        {
            firstName: "Kimi", lastName: "Shirasaki", phones: [
              { type: "Office", number: "(555) 444-2222" },
              { type: "Mobile", number: "(555) 999-1212" }]
        }
    ];
    self.employees(ko.utils.arrayMap(data,function (employee) {
        return { firstName: employee.firstName, lastName: employee.lastName, phones: ko.observableArray(employee.phones) };
    }))},5000);

self.addEmployee = function () {
    self.employees.push({
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        phones: ko.observableArray()
    });
};

self.removeEmployee = function (employee) {
    self.employees.remove(employee);
};

self.addPhone = function (employee) {
    employee.phones.push({
        type: "",
        number: ""
    });
};

self.removePhone = function (phone) {
    $.each(self.employees(), function () { this.phones.remove(phone) })
};

self.save = function () {
    self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.employees), null, 2));
};

self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("")
};



$(document).ready(function () {
ko.applyBindings(new EmployeesModel());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `loaded` observable and two different templates:

```
self.loaded = ko.observable(false);

self.activeTemplate = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.loaded() ? 'loaded' : 'loading';
});

<div class='NbiEmployees' data-bind="template: activeTemplate"></div>
```

Full example:

```js
var EmployeesModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.employees = ko.observableArray();

    self.loaded = ko.observable(false);
    
    self.activeTemplate = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.loaded() ? 'loaded' : 'loading';
    });

    self.loadData = function loadData() {
      self.loaded(false);
        
      setTimeout(function () {
        var data = [{
            firstName: "Graham",
            lastName: "Walsh",
            phones: [{
                type: "Office",
                number: "(555) 121-2121"
            }, {
                type: "Mobile",
                number: "(555) 123-4567"
            }]
        }, {
            firstName: "Kimi",
            lastName: "Shirasaki",
            phones: [{
                type: "Office",
                number: "(555) 444-2222"
            }, {
                type: "Mobile",
                number: "(555) 999-1212"
            }]
        }];
        self.employees(ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function (employee) {
            return {
                firstName: employee.firstName,
                lastName: employee.lastName,
                phones: ko.observableArray(employee.phones)
            };
        }));
          
        self.loaded(true);
     }, 5000);
        
    };

    self.addEmployee = function () {
        self.employees.push({
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
            phones: ko.observableArray()
        });
    };

    self.removeEmployee = function (employee) {
        self.employees.remove(employee);
    };

    self.addPhone = function (employee) {
        employee.phones.push({
            type: "",
            number: ""
        });
    };

    self.removePhone = function (phone) {
        $.each(self.employees(), function () {
            this.phones.remove(phone)
        })
    };

    self.save = function () {
        self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.employees), null, 2));
    };

    self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("")
    self.loadData();
};


ko.applyBindings(new EmployeesModel());
```

```css
body {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.NbiEmployees {
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: #EEEEDD;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    max-width: 655px;
}
.NbiEmployees input {
    font-family: Arial;
}
.NbiEmployees b {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.NbiEmployees p {
    margin-top: 0.9em;
    margin-bottom: 0.9em;
}
.NbiEmployees select[multiple] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 8em;
}
.NbiEmployees h2 {
    margin-top: 0.4em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.NbiEmployees TR {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.NbiEmployees TABLE, .NbiEmployees TD, .NbiEmployees TH {
    padding: 0.2em;
    border-width: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.NbiEmployees TD A {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.NbiEmployees table.contactsEditor > tbody > TR {
    border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
}
.NbiEmployees td input {
    width: 8em;
}
li {
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class='NbiEmployees' data-bind="template: activeTemplate"></div>

<script id="loading" type="text/html">
  <p>Loading, please wait</p>
</script>

<script id="loaded" type="text/html">
  <h2>NBI Employees</h2>
  <h3>NBI has <span data-bind="text: employees().length"></span> Employees</h3>

  <div id='employeesList'>
    <table class='employeesEditor'>
      <tr>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
        <th>Phone numbers</th>
      </tr>
      <tbody data-bind="foreach: employees">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input data-bind='value: firstName' />
            <div><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeEmployee'>Delete</a>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input data-bind='value: lastName' />
          </td>
          <td>
            
            <table>
              <tbody data-bind="foreach: phones">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <input data-bind='value: type' />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input data-bind='value: number' />
                  </td>
                  <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removePhone'>Delete</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            
            <a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.addPhone'>Add number</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <p>
    <button data-bind='click: addEmployee'>Add an Employee</button>
    <button data-bind='click: save, enable: employees().length > 0'>Save to JSON</button>
  </p>
  <textarea data-bind='value: lastSavedJson' rows='5' cols='60' disabled='disabled'></textarea>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A trick I like to do for this is basically have normal style tags hide the real content and then data-binds that will make the content div visible and hide the loading stuff when the bindings are applied.

```
<div id="realcontent" style="display:none"  data-bind="visible:true">
Content!
</div>
<div id="loadingdisplay" data=bind="visible:false">
 Loading display!
</div>
```

Then in my viewModels I always have a Load() where I do all the long running data loading/processing and I have a piece in my global js that does the actual load. So this way I dont have anything explicit in my viewmodels that has to do with this visible switching, I also dosnt have the processing of actual moving things around in the dom its just toggleing visibility. This Load function also allows me to do any setup that I need to do before the bindings are applied (like setting up computed observables)

```
viewModel.Load();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Now this stuff is mostly for initial loads, if its something triggered after the page has initially loaded then you can do the same idea with normal observables ala

```
<div id="realcontent" data-bind="visible:LoadingDone">
Content!
</div>
<div id="loadingdisplay" data=bind="visible:!LoadingDone()">
 Loading display!
</div>
```

Then when you start your load

```
LoadingDone(false)
```

and when it finishes
`LoadingDone(true)`

The performance on this stuff is really good even when theres a LOT of elements because your not actually altering the dom.

Answer (score 0):

In your viewmodel, you can add your own computed property "isLoaded" or some such (like `self.isLoaded = ko.observable(false);`, and then set your data-bind for the element that holds "NBI has X employees" to be `data-bind="enabled: isLoaded"`.  That way the element won't show until isLoaded is set to `true`.

```
<div data-bind="enabled: isLoaded">NBI has <span data-bind='employees().length'></span> employees</div>

self.isLoaded = ko.observable(false);
```

I suppose, you could also just put up a modal DIV (like jQuery dialog) if isLoaded = false, that would be your "Loading" screen.     Or just replace your entire content with a "loading" DIV, and the loading DIV is visiable on `isLoaded==false`, and the content container is viewable with `isLoaded==true`.   This way you get "Loading..." if the content is not yet loaded/not ready, and the actual viewmodel when it is.

Just some ideas.